# Understanding Minikube and the local IP address

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am very new to kubernetes. I'm using minikube to run a k8 cluster on local machine and deploy a Redis based docker image to it. I have the following question:

1. After starting the minikube. I get the following output when I run cluster info. I don't understand what this IP : 192.168.49.2:8443 is and where it is coming from ?

[image]

I read up online on minikube and have understood that it spins up a cluster by creating various vm's out of local machine. So I'm guessing the IP addr that I get here is a virtual IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`192.168.49.0/24` is used by the Minikube Docker driver as the default subnet. In greater detail, Minikube creates a bridge network on which the pods run; this network has this default subnet `192.168.49.0/24` with NAT. The subsequent Minikube container is on `192.168.49.2` IP.